# show ion-list over other elements

Tags: ionic4, ion-list

I'm doing simple CRUD operation and on retrieving the object I am getting the list all saved objects and I want to search the list of objects by name. But I don't want to use ion-searchbar instead I want to use ion-input and show suggestions in ion-list under ion-input but overlapping other elements like any other search bar(like google search). I have data in JSON format.
I also try to use ionic4-autocomplete but facing error like

**error image in ionic 4 app on auto complete**

[image]

The solution to any of the problem will help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

### Better List Filtering

There is a great project called [ionic-selectable](https://github.com/eakoriakin/ionic-selectable), which lets you have a nice searchable UI for lists of data.

### Autocomplete Error

The `formGroup` error is because you haven't added in the Reactive Forms reference.

Find this line in the related module:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

And change it to:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But first I want to give the suggestions at the bottom of my input bar and not on a new page. Second, do I have to just import 'ReactiveFormsModule' in my module or anything else?

Comment: Try adding that and then see what other errors come up. You haven't posted any code so it's just a guessing game.